# PUSH {lr} and POP {lr} in ARM Arch64

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

What is the equivalent instruction for `PUSH{lr}` and `POP{lr}` in ARM Arch64 instruction set .

Is `STR X30, [SP, #8]` correct ? could you please explain the concept of maintaining stack alignment ? I am relatively new to ARMv8 so excuse me.

Answer (score 8):

If you ask the C compiler to generate an assembly language listing from your source, you'll see how it handles pushing data on the stack for ARMv8. This might not be the only way to do it, but GCC does it this way:

```
   sub  sp, sp, #32     \\ Open up some temp stack space
   stp  x19, x20, [sp]  \\ save 2 pairs of registers
   stp  x21, x30, [sp,#16]
 <your code>
   ldp  x19, x20, [sp]  \\ restore 2 pairs of registers
   ldp  x21, x30, [sp,#16]
   add  sp, sp, #32     \\ "free" the temp stack space
```

Answer (score 6):

`STR X30, [SP, #8]` is totally wrong.

1. The most important point about Aarch64 stack is that `SP` **MUST BE 16 Byte aligned**.
2. Stack is descending. So `SP` should be moved left. `sub  sp, sp, #CONST`. In your example you actually mess up data of parent function.

If you need to preserve `LR` which is actually `x30` in Aarch64 use

```
str         x30,        [sp,#-16]!
```

Technically, it's possible to preserve on register only by

```
str         x30,        [sp,#-8]  // sp is not changed here! but data is written in permitted area
```

but with assumption that your function doesn't call any other subfunctions. But why on Earth save `LR` in this case?

Also Aarch64 could use any other register to perform return from a function. For example:

```
mov x7, x30 // preserve LR
blr .L.my.bloody.subroutine   // blr will mess up LR/x30
...
ret x7      // returning from function by using preserved req
```

In case you need to preserve more than 2 registers use example provided by @BitBank

Finally, you could not modify `pc`, so there is only one way to return by using `ret`

Comment: Do all AArch64 ABIs have a red-zone below the stack that won't be clobbered by signal handers, like the SystemV x86-64 ABI?  If there even are multiple ABIs, like there are for x86-64 (... thanks microsoft...).

Comment: @PeterCordes, Aarch64 procedure call standard doesn't have any mentioning of red-zone. So I don't have any ideas as well :)

Comment: So your suggestion of storing to `[sp,#-8]` isn't safe in programs that have signal handlers?  Interrupts of course use a separate kernel stack, but on x86 at least, signal handlers can clobber the space below the user-space stack at any time.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you're right, interruption is some sort of unplanned subroutine & could corrupt data. Thanks.

Comment: _The most important point about Aarch64 stack is that SP MUST BE 16 Byte aligned_. That should be changed to _The most important point about Aarch64 stack is that SP MUST BE 16 Byte aligned **when accessing memory**_. [link from ARM](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/using-the-stack-in-aarch64-implementing-push-and-pop)

Comment: Worth mentioning that you would restore it with: `ldr x30, [sp], 16;`.