# os x 32-bit printf from assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, 32-bit, libc

I'm back again - thanks to the kind folks here, especially @Jester and @PeterCordes, I have three out of my four target platforms working. I have Win 32 and Win 64 working, and I have OS X 64 working, but I can't seem to make OS X assembly work in 32-bit using the libc library.

I can do a "hello world" and other things using syscall (64-bit) and int 0x80 (32-bit), and I can make _printf work in 64-bit, but I can't manage to make it work in 32-bit.

In theory, I need to push the parameters onto the stack and then 16-byte align the stack, but I get a segmentation fault: 11 error when I run the code.

```
 8 section .data
 9 
10 hello   db  "Hello, world", 0x0a, 0x00
11 
12 section .text
13 
14 global _main
15 extern _printf, _exit
16 
17 _main:
18     push hello
19     sub esp, 12     ; 16-byte align stack
20     call _printf
21 
22     add esp, 16     ; undo stack alignment
23     push 0
24     sub esp, 12     ; 16-byte align stack
25     call _exit
```

I've tried it without the stack aligning code and I get the same error. I've found various samples online and I could not make them work, and I've even done the trick with using GCC to output Intel-syntax assembler and I could not manage to translate it to nasm.

I'm using nasm because it works on Windows, OS X, and Linux, so that way I only need to learn one assembler syntax.

I realize that all the Intel Macs are 64-bit, but they can run 32-bit code so I want to be able to follow it and understand it. This is all aimed at helping me reverse-engineer malware.

Thanks

Comment: You had trouble translating `gcc -masm=intel` output to NASM?  That's weird; it's a lot like MASM, so it's basically the same except they write `DWORD PTR` instead of `DWORD`.  You could always just use a disassembler that outputs correct nasm syntax, e.g. Agner Fog's excellent `objconv` disassembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions always look for their arguments just above the return address.  If you `sub esp, 12` after pushing something, **the args include 12 bytes of garbage**.

Also, 12 is the wrong amount of space.  ESP is 16-byte aligned *before* a `call`, [according to the ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612443/why-does-the-mac-abi-require-16-byte-stack-alignment-for-x86-32), so the start of the stack args is 16-byte aligned.  But `call` pushes a return address, so on entry to a function `ESP+4` and `ESP-12` are the nearest alignment boundaries.

`sub esp,12` at the top of `main` would align the stack by 16.  But you doing another `push` as well, which also moves ESP before `call`

Your 2 options are  `sub esp, 8` / `push hello`  or
`sub esp,12` / `mov dword [esp], hello`.

```
_main:                ; ESP was 16-byte aligned *before* call pushed a return address
    sub   esp, 8      ; get ESP to 4 bytes above an alignment boundary
    push  hello       ; ESP is now 16-byte aligned.
    call  _printf

    mov   dword [esp], 0    ; defer popping the stack
    call  _exit
    ;add   esp, 4+8        ; pop args+padding.  But exit doesn't return
    ;ret

    section .rodata      ; You don't need to write this string, so put it in rodata

     hello   db  "Hello, world", 0x0a, 0x00
```

---

> all the Intel Macs are 64-bit

Not strictly true: the very first gen Intel macs used Intel Core CPUs (basically Pentium-M), not Core2.  If they'd waited one generation, they never would have needed to care much about 32bit.

Although at this point, I assume it's considered safe to distribute binaries that don't work on 32bit-only OS X.

Comment: Hi Peter. That makes sense about the stack - I thought it looked odd, and the worst thing is that is exactly what I saw on some web sites supposedly explaining how to do this.

I guess I'm messing up the linking now, because it assembles but generates a Segmentation Fault: 11 error.

Comment: @querist: use the `file` command to make sure it's a 32bit binary.  Or use `gcc -m32 hello.o` to link.  Look at the output of `objdump -d -Mintel`, or whatever disassembler you like, to see what happened to your binary.  Or better yet, run it under gdb.  Using a debugger is essential for learning asm.  (gdb has an intel-syntax mode.  put `set disassembly-flavor intel` in your `~/.gdbinit`)

Comment: It's a 32-bit executable alright. I am receiving a warning about absolute addressing in _main:

ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from hello32x.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie

Still getting a segmentation fault. I did not expect it to be this difficult to make it work in 32-bit with libc.

Comment: The latest versions of OS X come with lldb instead. I'll get more familiar with it.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're still stuck with getting 32bit to link, ask a new question.  This Q&A is stuck being about the bug in passing args, which applies to 32bit Windows and Linux, too, since they use the same calling convention.  OS X has a lot of rules about position independent code, but I'm surprised they apply in 32bit where RIP-relative addressing isn't available.  I guess that makes 32bit code on OS X suck even worse than 32bit on other OSes.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I'll do that. I'm working through it with the debugger now.