# Calling the C-function _printf from NASM causes a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, mach-o

I've been trying to learn 64-bit assembly on both Mac-OS and Windows using NASM.

My code is

```
extern _printf

section .data
    msg db "Hello World!", 10, 0

section .text
    global _main

_main:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, msg
    call _printf

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

and I compile it with

```
nasm -f macho64 -o main.o main.asm 
gcc -o main main.o
```

While trying to call `_printf`, I got the error

> Segmentation fault: 11

When I remove the call to `_printf`, my code runs fine.
Why does the call to `_printf` cause a segmentation fault?

I have found the ABI Calling Convention [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI), but had no luck successfully calling a C-function.

I would expect `Hello World!` to be printedd, however I get 'Segmentation Fault: 11' instead.

Comment: Are you sure that `mov rdi, msg` is being encoded as `mov r64, imm64` and not `mov r/m64, imm32`? Try using `mov rdi, qword msg` instead.

Comment: You might try to call that function in C and look at the created assembler output.

Comment: @Michael I changed the line, and the output has not changed.

Comment: @Gerhardh I have tried doing that before, however I have a hard time understanding the vast majority of it besides the very basic, especially because of the different syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>~~You need to setup a stack frame before calling `_printf`</strike>

**TL;DR:** The  System V AMD64 ABI requires the stack-pointer to be 16-byte-aligned. By the time of calling `_printf`, the stack-pointer is misaligned by 8 bytes.

Debugging the binary with LLDB gives:

> frame #0: 0x00007fff527d430a libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error

MacOS uses the System V AMD64 ABI and therefore relies on 16-byte alignment for the stack-pointer ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612443/why-does-the-mac-abi-require-16-byte-stack-alignment-for-x86-32)), in short this means the stack-pointer (`rsp`) should always be divisible by 16 when calling a function.

By the time of calling `_printf`, the stack-pointer (`rsp`) is misaligned by 8 bytes. How did this come?

I found the answer on [this page](http://sevanspowell.net/posts/learning-nasm-on-macos.html), calling the `_main` function pushes the return address (8 bytes) on the stack and therefore misaligns it.

My initial idea - the setup of the stack frame - pushed another address on the stack and therefore `rsp` was divisible by 16 again.

However an easier solution would be just `sub rsp, 8` as suggested by  [Margaret Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5801661/margaret-bloom)

Change your code to:

```
extern _printf

section .data
    msg: db "Hello World!", 10, 0

section .text
    global _main

_main:
    ;; Fix the stack alignment
    sub rsp, 8
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, msg
    call _printf

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Tested on macOS 10.13.6

Comment: Have you tested it *without* the "stack frame"?

Comment: Yes and I got the same error as described in the question

Comment: How about, `sub rsp, 8` instead of the two instructions? I forgot the OP is using the CRT, so the execution starts in `main` which misaligned the stack with its return address. The `mov rbp, rsp` is superfluous.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, of course your are right. I realized my mistake and updated my answer